# Prove that the integral of $e^{k\cos t}\cos(k\sin t)$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ equals $2\pi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, bessel-functions

Prove that $$I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{k\cos t}\cos(k\sin t)\,dx=2\pi$$ and prove that $$J=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{k\cos t}\sin(k\sin t)\,dx=0$$ 
With the help of the following integral: $$H=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{kz}}{z}\,dx$$ 
I proved that the  : $$H=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{kz}}{z}\,dx=2i\pi$$ and I proved that $$I+iJ=\frac{H}{i}=2\pi$$but what should I do next to prove that$I=2\pi$ or to prove that$J=0$? Is it by using 
$Re(z)=\cos t$?

Comment: Did you mean $e^{k\cos t} \cos(k\sin t)$ ?

Comment: No not that it's $e^{kcos t}cos(ksin t)$

Comment: $2\pi$ is purely real, so.... ?

Comment: By equating the coefficient. Any imaginary no. is in the form of $a+ib$ Since the coefficient of the imaginary component is $0$, $J=0$ and the coefficient of the real component is $2\pi$, $I=2\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proved that the  : $$H=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{kz}}{z}\,dx=2i\pi$$ and I proved that $$I+iJ=\frac{H}{i}=2\pi$$but what should I do next to prove that$I=2\pi$ or to prove that$J=0$? 
Since $ t $ is Real Number, both of the integrals $I$ and $J$ are Real. Which means we can compare both sides of the equation $$I+iJ=2\pi$$ , $$I+iJ=2\pi+0i$$ which leads to $$I=2\pi$$ $$J=0$$. 
End of solution.